# Parentheses in Block Brackets in RegEx

Tags: regex, backreference

I need a RegEx that matches the following:

```
(whatever)   3.4  Temp
(whatever)   7.8  Name
(whatever)  10.0  Other Name
```

Basically, it has to match whatever in the beginning, and then either two spaces, two digits, a dot and a digit or three spaces, one digit, a dot, and a digit, followed by two spaces and whatever.

This is easily matched with this RegEx:

```
.*?  [\s|\d]\d\.\d  .*?
```

However, I want to extract the decimal number and whatever's after it using a backreference.  I was trying

```
.*?  [\s(\d\.\d)|(\d\d\.\d)]  (.*?)
```

However, referring to it with \1,\2 doesn't work, I think because the parentheses I'm referring to are in the optional square brackets with the '|' symbol. Is there a solution?

Comment: `|` does not mean "or" in a character class. I don't think you should be using a character class here at all...

Comment: @MattBall Jeez I'm an idiot.  It's amazing what you just look over.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just pull the space out of the character class.

```
.*?\s+([\d.]+)
```

However since `\d` is literally `[0123456789.]`, just drop the character class. And since `.*?` will match those leading spaces too, drop the `\s` too!

```
.*?(\d+)
```